# How to retrieve struts2 checkboxlist values

Tags: struts2, checkboxlist

I will create a list with checkboxlist. For those I use following code:

```
<s:form action="accept" namespace="/manager/course">  
    <s:checkboxlist list="courseRequests" name="acceptList" listValue="studentNickname" listKey="studentId" theme="checkbox-fix"/>  
    <s:url action="accept" namespace="/manager/course" var="accList" />
    <s:a href="%{accList}"><s:text name="Accept"/> </s:a>
</s:form>
```

It work fine a create a check box list, that you can see its pic in the following:
[image]

and this is html code generated by above code:

```
<form id="accept" name="accept" action="/ESA/manager/course/accept.action" method="post">
    <table class="wwFormTable">
    <table class="gradienttable">   
    <tr>
        <th class="row"><p>Row</p></th>
        <th style="width: 240px;"><p>Student</p></th>
        <th ><p>Accept</p></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td id="row"><p><label>1</label></p></td>
         <td style="width:250px;"><p>
                <label for="acceptList-1" class="checkboxLabel">Mansour Barzegar</label>
            </p></td>
         <td style="text-align:center;"><p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="acceptList" value="5" id="acceptList-1"                </p></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td id="row"><p><label>2</label></p></td>
         <td style="width:250px;"><p>
                <label for="acceptList-2" class="checkboxLabel">Ali Mahmoudi</label>
            </p></td>
         <td style="text-align:center;"><p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="acceptList" value="6" id="acceptList-2"                </p></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td id="row"><p><label>3</label></p></td>
         <td style="width:250px;"><p>
                <label for="acceptList-3" class="checkboxLabel">Masih Zare</label>
            </p></td>
         <td style="text-align:center;"><p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="acceptList" value="7" id="acceptList-3"                </p></td>
     </tr>
     </table>
     <a href="/ESA/manager/course/accept.action">Accept</a>
     </table>
</form>
```

In the Action Class I tried to retrive seleced checkbox value by following code:

```
private int[] acceptList;
public void setAcceptList(int[] acceptList){
    this.acceptList=acceptList;
}
```

and several other code but I all states I get `null`.
Do I use wrong code?

Comment: Before retrieving it in the code you need to send it.

Comment: @AleksandrM opes. i think my mind hanged :D. i was tried and forgot it.

Answer (score 2):

in your markup, do this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="thename" id="checkbox_id1" value="value1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="thename" id="checkbox_id2" value="value2" />
```

in your action (or object) do this:

```
// action/object code...
Set<String> cbox = new HashSet();

public void setThename(String[] thenames) {
    for (String thename : thenames) {
        cbox.add(thename);
    }
}
// action/object code...
```

---

**notice the checkbox name matches the setter name, e.g. element name == someName and method == setSomeName**

**Same would apply for Set<Integer>, but you use int[] thenames as the argument. You could also use Integer[] thenames for the argument.**

---

to test output:

```
if (cbox != null) {
   for (String s : cbox) {
     log.info(s);
   }
}
```

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/using-checkboxes.html